# Using Handlebars with Node.js/Express, need login and logout to render according to user signing in

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, rendering

Hoping someone can help me with this. I am using Handlebars as a template engine with Node/Express blog I am building.  I am trying to get the login and logout buttons rendered according to when the user is logged in or not.
I know I need to use the session somehow but I thought I was using the syntax correctly. I have rendered everything else I was doing but I am stumped on this one.

```
       {{#if sessionSwitch}}
        <a class="blog-nav-item" href="/auth/logout">
          <p class="nav-fonts">Logout</p>
        </a>
        {{else}}
        <a class="blog-nav-item" href="/auth/login">
          <p class="nav-fonts">Login</p>
        </a>
        {{/if}}
```

Here is the controller where I am sure I need to use the session.

```
module.exports = async (req, res) => {
const {
    email,
    password
} = req.body;
// try to find the user
await User.findOne({
    email
}, (error, user) => {
    if (user) {
        // compare passwords.
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (error, same) => {
            if (same) {
                // store user session.
                const sessionSwitch = req.session
                sessionSwitch.userId = user._id
                res.redirect('/')
                console.log({ Message: "Success"})
            } else {
                res.redirect('/auth/login')
            }
        })
    } else {
         res.redirect('/auth/login')
    }
})
```

}

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think your first step is to understand _how_ you are persisting your user's session. Are you using an opaque session stored on the server? Or a JASON Web Token (JWT) stored on the client? Next, you will need to leverage whichever mechanism on _each_ request in order to know whether to show the private state. You may want to consider using an auth library like http://www.passportjs.org/

Comment: Thanks for everyone for responding. I figured out what the problem was. Instead of focusing on the controller the problem was in my auth middleware. I just used  a boolean variable stating it to true:
res.locals.isLoggedIn = true
Passed the isLoggedIn in the handlebars if conditional and it rendered properly.